# Remove Date from slugs in an excel file with Python script

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime, formula

I am having a hard time figuring out how to remove the date from the end of a slug for an excel file that I am trying to clean up to automate a process for one of our tasks.

**Here is what the slugs look like:**

turnpike-troubadours-14-december-2023

the-rock-orchestra-20-november-2023

one-night-of-tina-a-tina-turner-tribute-show-12-december-2023

darlene-love-15-december-2023

monmouth-civic-chorus-rejoice-greatly-17-december-2023

holiday-express-19-december-2023

black-nativity-30-december-2023

**I want them to look like:**

turnpike-troubadours

the-rock-orchestra

one-night-of-tina-a-tina-turner-tribute-show

darlene-love

monmouth-civic-chorus-rejoice-greatly

holiday-express

black-nativity

I have tried various codes I have found on the internet like:

```
def remove_date_from_end_of_string(string):
    return string.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
    return df

outlinks_df['Artist Path'] = outlinks_df['Artist Path'].apply(remove_date_from_end_of_string)
```

Artist Path is the column in the file that needs to be cleaned up.
I keep getting an error when I try this formula, and honestly, I am not sure what it is doing.

I am new to python and I am trying to automate some of the tedious tasks my team does weekly.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: I would use find() to find one of the 12 months then 2 "-" back... Or find the first number and left() with number position -2

Answer (score 0):

If they all have the exact same format, this will do:

```py
a = "aholiday-express-19-december-2023"
print("-".join(a.split("-")[:-3]))
```

Do this for every slug.

Your function would go like this:

```py
def remove_date_from_end_of_string(string):
    return "-".join(string.split("-")[:-3])
```

Logic is to split the string whenever a "-" occurs and then to join it back without the last three elements :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the right delimiter (`-`) and adjust the `maxsplit` of [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) :

```
def remove_date_from_end_of_string(string):
    return string.rsplit('-', 3)[0] # <-- line updated

outlinks_df['Artist Path'] = (
    outlinks_df['Artist Path'].apply(remove_date_from_end_of_string)
)
```

Note that you can avoid using a custom function and use pandas [*String methods*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) :

```
outlinks_df['Artist Path'].str.rsplit("-", n=3).str[0]

outlinks_df['Artist Path'].str.replace("-\d{2}-\w+-\d{4}$", "", regex=True)

# and many more variants..
```

Output :

```
>>> print(outlinks_df)

                                    Artist Path
0                          turnpike-troubadours
1                            the-rock-orchestra
2  one-night-of-tina-a-tina-turner-tribute-show
3                                  darlene-love
4         monmouth-civic-chorus-rejoice-greatly
5                               holiday-express
6                                black-nativity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` function `pandas` library.

```
df['Artist Path'].str.replace('-\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-\d{4}$', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a possibility using Excel:

```
TEXTJOIN("-",1,REDUCE(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",,,,)*1)),"",PROPER((TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",,,,)))),$G$2:$G$13,LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,OFFSET(b,0,1)))))
```

[image]

The steps are to split the bits, replace numbers and month with blank and then recombine.